# Using the map/mapM function to return a String ready for putStrLn to separate list elements

Tags: haskell, dictionary, newline

I am trying to create a function of the type:

```
f1 :: [Car] -> String
```

where Car is a declared type that is a tuple containing a String, an Int and a List of further tuples. I want to use a `map` function in order to return a String which will be passed into the `main` function, and then output as separated strings.

Anyway, I have a main function that calls on the function f1 as follows:

```
putStrLn(f1 listOfCars)
```

where listOfCars is declared as you'd expect...

```
[("Ford", "Mondeo", 2009, [("Autotrader", 12000), ("Parkers", 11500)]), 

("VW", "Golf", 2011, [("Autotrader", 16000), ("Parkers", 15250)]),...]
```

I did this successfully using a recursive function with patterns and guards and the `show` function, but having looked into both the `map` and `mapM`/`mapM_` function I'm certain I can use one of them, somehow, to do this in a far more efficient manner. I was looking for some help on how to use one of those functions.

Comment: What's your question...?

Comment: @DanielWagner How can I use the `map`, `mapM` or `mapM_` function to do this?

Comment: You haven't said what "this" is yet! Show us your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will first need to create a new function that converts a single car to a viewable string

```
carToString::Car->String
carToString car = <fill this in as you would like>
```

Note that this function is way more reusable than f1 above!  It can be used as a building block to work with Cars stored in any container (trees, etc).

Once you have this, you can print the whole thing as follows

```
putStrLn $ unlines $ map carToString listOfCars
```

Alternatively, you can use forM_ (which is just `flip mapM_`) as follows

```
forM_ listOfCars $ \car -> do
    putStrLn $ carToString car
```

or if you prefer terseness,

```
forM_ listOfCars $ putStrLn . carToString
```

---

Note that the first method can be modified to give an alternate definition of f1....

```
putStrLn $ unlines $ map carToString listOfCars
```

is the same thing as

```
putStrLn (unlines . map carToString $ listOfCars)
```

so, f1 can be defined as

```
f1 = unlines . map carToString
```

which is a very clean way to define f1.

Comment: I am given a database of cars called `listOfCars` and am looking for a way to use just one function to prepare the list for the `putStrLn` function... The way the `main` function works is by simply calling `putStrLn(f1 listOfCars)` so while yours works it's not quite appropriate to my task.

Comment: What you want is actually in my answer, I'll update to make it more clear.

Comment: I've added a section that shows you how to derive f1 from the first method.